# Solving $9^{1+\log x} - 3^{1+\log x} - 210 = 0$ where base of log is $3$ for $x$

Tags: logarithms

Question is to solve the equation for value of $x$.

> $$9^{1+\log x} - 3^{1+\log x} - 210 = 0; \quad \text{where base of log is }3$$

The answer given is $x=5$

I've tried to solve it. And got two values of $x= -14/3$ and $x=5$.  What I've done wrong?

[image: [enter image description here]]

Comment: Use $a^{\log_b(x)} = x^{\log_b(a)}$.

Comment: The final step should be $(3k+14)(k-5)=0$ (multiplication since you are factoring) This is what then allows you to reach your conclusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have solved correctly just made one error towards the end.
Note that the domain of $\log(x)$ is $x > 0$ so $x=-14/3$ is rejected as it is not in the domain of the function.

Comment: Yep.  And going from $(3 x + 14) + (x - 5) = 0$ does not mean that either term in the sum is $0$.

Comment: He meant$(3x+14)(x-5) = 0$. He was solving a quadratic. Must be $\times$ in the middle.

Comment: Oh! I didn't noticed that.